# Inner joins on 3 tables with one known variable

Tags: php, mysql, join

I tried a couple of the other answers but I still can't get my brain around this. Maybe if my specific problem is worked out I can understand how to join three tables.

I have these tables:

```
invoice
id - 

invoiceItem
id - invId - itemId - discode

item
id - name - cid(categoryID) - price - memprice - attendee_price

category
id - catName
```

I query for invoices and get there id's and then run a while loop to:
get the list of invoice items, the details of those items by id, and the category by id.

this is the query i am attempting but am hung up on the joins and where clause

```
while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($invoice_query){      
//my invoice id is $r['id']

    $iQ = mysql_query("SELECT 
          item.id, item.cid, item.name, item.memprice, item.attendee_price, item.price,
          invoiceItem.discode, 
          categories.id, categories.catName
          FROM invoiceItem 
          INNER JOIN categories ON item.cid=categories.id 
          INNER JOIN item ON ?????? 
          WHERE invoiceItem.id='$r[id]'");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ON conditions for `INNER JOINS` typically consist of 
`leftTable.foreignKey = rightTable.primaryKey`...in your case you needed to add a join for the invoice table so you match its primary key to the foreign key in the invoiceItem table `(invoice.id = invoiceItem.invId)`

```
SELECT 
          item.id, item.cid, item.name, item.memprice, item.attendee_price, item.price,
          invoiceItem.discode, 
          categories.id, categories.catName
          FROM invoiceItem 
          INNER JOIN item ON item.id = invoiceItem.itemId 
          INNER JOIN categories ON item.cid=categories.id 
          INNER JOIN invoice ON invoice.id = invoiceItem.invId
          WHERE invoice.id='$ir[id]'
```

Comment: Also add some brief in your post

Comment: ON conditions for INNER JOINS typically consist of "leftTable.foreignKey = rightTable.primaryKey"...in your case you needed to add a join for the invoice table so you match its primary key to the foreign key in the invoiceItem table (invoice.id = invoiceItem.invId)

Comment: I mean to say add the brief in your answer not in comment :)

Comment: i made a mistake in my where clause... I am selecting from the invoiceItem table by $r['id'] which is the id from the Invoice table... does that change the where clause?

Comment: should it be where invoiceItem.invId=$r['id']

Comment: dang... i am getting an error: Unknown column 'item.cid' in 'on clause' - - cid is definitely in the item table.

Comment: thats because the item table wasnt joined yet...try the answer now lol

Comment: That appears to be working. I have a couple of kinks to work out with the display but i think this gets me going in the right direction... Thank You